# How to retrieve attribute name for custom widget in Thingsboard with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, thingsboard

I am trying to retrieve an attribute name in HTML by calling a javascript in scope function called `AttributeName` however I keep being returned ctx.AttributeName is not a function in the widget window. I thought that  this is because the html is being loaded first before the javascript, so I added `ng-if="AttributeName"` in the html however no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

My JS and Angular knowledge is limited and I come from a C/C++ background. Trying to do and learn as much as I can until we find a good JS dev.

HTML where I am calling AttributeName

```
    <thead ng-if="AttributeName">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">{{ AttributeName(0) }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Javascript

```
self.onInit = function() {

    var $scope = self.ctx.$scope;
    $scope.AttributeName = function(index) {
        return $scope.ctx.data[0].datasource.name;
    };
}
```

Using:

- ThingsBoard: 3.5.1

Comment: are you using `AngularJS` or `Angular`? Angular (the modern framework) doesn't have any `ng-if`, is `*ngIf`. If you are using the deprecated `AngularJs`, remove the `Angular` tag